# Custom domain name for github pages only works for homepage, all other 404

Tags: reactjs, github, react-router, github-pages

I just linked a custom domain I got from google domains to a github pages react app. Currentely, when I go to the custom domain, the homepage of the website works fine, however, when I click on any links, firstly, the react-router doesn't change pages. And Secondly, when I reload the page, it still just loads the homepage and returns a 404 error.

Here is the repository with all the code: https://github.com/Been-H/ridge-road-journal-website

And on google domains, I have these as my type A records:

185.199.108.153
185.199.109.153
185.199.110.153
185.199.111.153

And this as my CNAME I have host name www and the data is my github (been-h.github.io

Does anyone know why only the homepage is working and nothing else? Thanks!

Comment: You should use a `HashRouter` for apps running in Github pages. Does this help answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/71985764/8690857

Comment: Just made the change, however, it still isnt routing to other pages besides home. Also, when I go to the network tab of dev tools, when I click any links, it doesn't make a call for the info on the new page, I have to refresh that page. Even then, it is still giving me 404 error

Comment: Actually @DrewReese it is now working for all pages except for one, the author-dash page. When I click on it, the code runs history.push('#/na') and it returns this in the url: https://ridgeroadjournal.org/na#/. Do you know why this is happening?

Comment: I don't think you need the `"#"` in the target path. Try just `history.push("/na");`.

Comment: Your "homepage" in package.json should be your custom domain