# Is it possible to create a multi-paged website using Github Pages and Yew?

Tags: rust, web-deployment, github-pages, yew

I've just begun creating a portfolio website using Rust and Yew. I wasn't planning on doing any server-side logic so naturally I thought Github Pages fit my needs.

Here is my code for the Yew site.

```
#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy, PartialEq, Routable)]
enum AppRoute {
    #[at("/")]
    Home,
    #[at("/about")]
    About,
    #[not_found]
    #[at("/404")]
    NotFound,
}

#[function_component]
fn App() -> Html {
    html! {
        <>
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Switch<AppRoute> render={
                    |route| match route {
                        AppRoute::Home => html! { <h1>{ "Hello, world!" }</h1> },
                        AppRoute::About => html! {
                            <>
                                <h1>{ "About" }</h1>
                                <p> { "This page was created using " }
                                    <a href="https://www.rust-lang.org/">{ "Rust" }</a> {", "}
                                    <a href="https://yew.rs/">{ "Yew" }</a> {" and "}
                                    <a href="https://trunkrs.dev/">{ "Trunk" }</a> 
                                    { "." }
                                </p>
                            </>
                        },
                        AppRoute::NotFound => html! { <h1>{ "404: Page not found." }</h1> },
                    }
                } />
            </BrowserRouter>
        </>
    }
}

fn main() {
    yew::Renderer::<App>::new().render();
}
```

I am using the [yew-router](https://crates.io/crates/yew-router) crate for routing to different pages. For example changing the url to `website.github.io/about` would route me to the `about` page, defined in the `AppRoute` enum.

However when I do try and type this in the browser URL I get a Github 404 page not found. I assume  this is because Github is trying to find a repository named `about` and cannot.

How would I be able to use multiple pages in the URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the following Stack Overflow answers my theory is you need to use a [HashRouter](https://docs.rs/yew-router/latest/yew_router/router/struct.HashRouter.html).  Although these focus on React the essential issue is the same with Yew

- [Why is HashRouter not working when BrowserRouter works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73330315/why-is-hashrouter-not-working-when-browserrouter-works)  (for GitHub Pages)
- [What is the difference between HashRouter and BrowserRouter in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51974369/what-is-the-difference-between-hashrouter-and-browserrouter-in-react)  (background)

Caveat: I'm new to Yew and have no experience with GitHub Pages.  I just came across this while looking into Yew routing recently.  Here are some others more specific to Rust/Yew:

- [How to deploy wasm rust website on github pages](https://old.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/10eiysf/how_to_deploy_wasm_rust_website_on_github_pages)
- [Rust Wasm Github with Yew](https://plippe.github.io/blog/2021/07/12/rust-wasm-github.html)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Using a HashRouter works perfectly. Thanks!