# Why does my React Website fail to load up images and videos when deployed to GitHub pages?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, github-pages

[This](https://github.com/jonathanakhagbosu/react-travel-website) is the GitHub repo for a react travel website I created using MaterialUI and react-router-dom. When I run the app on my local server, it runs just fine. However, when I [deployed](https://jonathanakhagbosu.github.io/react-travel-website/) it to GitHub pages, I began to get some issues:

1. On initial load, only the header and footer shows. The main section is absent.
2. When I click on the homepage, the videos and pictures do not load.
3. When I refresh the page, it returns a 404 error page.

What do I do?

Comment: Does this help answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/71985764/8690857

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help. I've tried this but the same issue still occurs.

Comment: Try removing the trailing `"/"` from the `"homepage"` entry in the package.json file, and remove the `basename` prop from the router.

Answer (score 0):

I have taken a look through your code.

In `App.js` file. Try to change this

```
  <Router basename = {"/"}>
    <Navbar />
      <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="/services" element={<Services />} />
      ...
    </Routes>
    <Footer />
  </Router>
```

to

```
  <Router>
    <Navbar />
      <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="/services" element={<Services />} />
      ...
    </Routes>
    <Footer />
  </Router>
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help but I still have the same issue even after making the changes you suggested.

Comment: I have cloned your repo. Do some changes following my answer above,  adjust syntax errors `class` to `className` of React in `Footer.jsx` file and my deployment works fine. Also, you should notice the `key` `item` warning of React, this does not affect the deployment process but it's better to be fixed.