# My deployed site isn't displaying on gh-pages but display on localhost

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github-pages

So I have this problem when I try to deploy to gh-pages after everything the page ends up being white but if I go to localhost:3000 everything is working just fine this is the GitHub pages link

https://greatkali419.github.io/coding_challenge/

Then this is my repo link
https://github.com/greatkali419/coding_challenge

I tried deleting the repo and upload again but it's not working

Comment: Maybe this post will answer your question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71984401/react-router-not-working-with-github-pages

Comment: Now seems to work.

Comment: I removed `git` and `github` tags - this doesn't seem to be a git related issue.

Answer (score -1):

Your code and configuration are absolutely fine, but you didn't remove the /build directory from the .gitignore file. That's why your live gh-pages didn't read the build file.

Comment: It was a router problem... It's solved now thanks everyone