# Error 404 on Github Pages using React Router v6.6.1 and Vite

Tags: reactjs, react-router, web-deployment, github-pages, vite

I'm trying to publish my first React app using Vite, React-Router-Dom-v6.6.1 and Github Pages but for some reason the `index.html` file is not detected and the "404 error" is being shown, however this error is shown on a page added by me to deal with possible errors and there is an option to return to the homepage ; however this homepage is generated from the reading of the `index.html` file and respective javascript. But at this moment the browser is already able to interpret the `index.html` file and everything behaves similarly to the development environment, without errors.
That is, for some reason the browser does not identify the `index.html` file on its first load (I think), even though the path pointed in `base: "/presentation/"` is pointing to the right place.

Below are the files I find most relevant, the link to my `Github Pages` (where this issue is happening) as well as a link to a screen recording I made of this situation so you can better understand what I'm trying to explain.

[**Github Page in question:**](https://cristianolm.github.io/presentation/)

[**Problem screen recording video:**](https://youtu.be/b-R7g0JFcHk)

## VITE files

---

**main.jsx**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import {
  createBrowserRouter,
  RouterProvider,
  createRoutesFromElements,
  Route,
} from "react-router-dom";
import "./index.css";

// Redux Toolkit
import { Provider, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import store from "./reduxTlk/store";

/* existing imports */
import Root from "./routes/root";
import ErrorPage from "./error-page";
import Home from "./routes/home";
import WeatherStatus from "./routes/weatherStatus";
import { weatherLoader } from "./components/projects/ipma/TempTable";

const router = createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <>
      <Route path="/" element={<Root />} errorElement={<ErrorPage />}>
        <Route index element={<Home />} />
        <Route
          path="WeatherStatus"
          element={<WeatherStatus />}
          loader={weatherLoader}
        />
      </Route>
    </>
  )
);

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <RouterProvider router={router} />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "vite-project",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.5",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.5",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.11.0",
    "@mui/material": "^5.11.7",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.1",
    "dompurify": "^2.4.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.6.1"
  },
  "homepage": "https://cristianolm.github.io/presentation/",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.0.24",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.8",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^2.2.0",
    "vite": "^3.2.3"
  }
}
```

**vite.config.js**

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  base: "/presentation/",
  plugins: [react()],
});
```

## dist/`index.html`

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/presentation/vite.svg" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Cristiano Martins</title>
    <script type="module" crossorigin src="/presentation/assets/index.6cda9410.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/presentation/assets/index.85f54fc4.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Firstly, I tried to build for production with the `base line: "/presentation/,` in *vite.config.js*, then I tried to do this same process without this line and finally I added that line again, but I added it to the *package. json* the line `homepage": "https://cristianolm.github.io/presentation/,`.

And of course I tried to search for another solution on google, but without success.

Comment: Does this help answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71984401/react-router-not-working-with-github-pages/71985764#71985764

Comment: I had already seen this post, I just didn't use "HashRouter", because in the latest version React-Router advises using "createBrowserRouter".

Comment: The RRD docs have just about always said that, but [Github hosting requires using a `HashRouter`](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#github-pages) from my understanding. It's more of a "Use the `BrowserRouter` unless you have an edge-case use case and you know what you are doing." sort of thing.

Comment: Hmmmm... Well that could be it. I think I'll try other hosting services to see if I come to a better conclusion.
But that could very well be it.

But when I've tested more options I'll come here to say something. Now I'm going to rest a little, because I'm already many hours back from this. But I promise I'll come here to update.

Comment: Hello. I've been back from this and other errors and I realized that the answer that the "Tachibana Shin" of re-invoicing the routes (in my case) resulting from the addition of `path="/presentation"` in "Route" solved the problem.
As for the other hosting services, I tried the Vercel website, but there was an error related to the routes, but I confess that I didn't invest a lot of time trying to solve this problem, as I was trying to solve the Github Pages problem.
But still thanks for the help.

Comment: I think Tachibana-shin's answer only masks the issue. I suspect what you really need is to simply specify the `basename` prop on the router for the directory the app is hosted in, i.e. `createBrowserRouter(routes, { basename: "/presentation" })`. Their answer *effectively* did this, but not quite in the idiomatic RRD way.

Comment: After all this time, I noticed that you are right in your answer. I redid my entire portfolio for TypeScript and tried to solve this Github Pages hosting issue again, and I noticed that you were right, however, it only worked for me when I indicated the name of the repository (where the github page would take place) in both places: `vite .config.ts` with ` base: "/presentation",` and in ``createBrowserRouter` with `{ basename: "/presentation" }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you may only need to additionally specify/indicate that the router is running from a sub-directory, beyond what is already specified in the package.json and the vite.config files. You can specify a [`basename`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/create-browser-router#basename) prop on the router that matches the directory the app is hosted from and all routes and links will work relative to this location.

> `basename`
>
> The basename of the app for situations where you can't deploy to the
> root of the domain, but a sub directory.
>
> ```
> createBrowserRouter(routes, {
>   basename: "/app",
> });
> ```

For the host: `"https://cristianolm.github.io/presentation"`

Example:

```
const router = createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <Route
      path="/" // <-- "/presentation"
      element={<Root />}
      errorElement={<ErrorPage />}
    >
      <Route
        index // <-- "/presentation"
        element={<Home />}
      />
      <Route
        path="WeatherStatus" // <-- "/presentation/WeatherStatus"
        element={<WeatherStatus />}
        loader={weatherLoader}
      />
    </Route>
  ),
  { basename: "/presentation" }
);
```

Comment: I managed to solve the problem, but the name of your repository must be indicated in both places (and not just in one).
Those locations are the `vite .config.ts` file (as I indicated in my question) and the Router `createBrowserRouter` (as indicated in this answer).
Thanks.

Comment: @Cristianolm Yes, sorry, I did intend for that to mean "... you may only *additionally* need to ...". I'll edit to make this more clear. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

this is not really vite related i think you understand:

```
const router = createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <>
-     <Route path="/" element={<Root />} errorElement={<ErrorPage />}>
+     <Route path="/presentation" element={<Root />} errorElement={<ErrorPage />}>
        <Route index element={<Home />} />
        <Route
          path="WeatherStatus"
          element={<WeatherStatus />}
          loader={weatherLoader}
        />
      </Route>
    </>
  )
);
```

it looks like this:
https://cristianolm.github.io/presentation/
the actual route will be `/presentation` not `/`

Comment: I don't think it's Vite-related either, more like React Router.
But I don't think that can be it, because "/presentation" is the name of the repo, hence having written "base: "/presentation/" in `vite.config.js`.
But if you click on the video I put associated with "Problem screen recording video:" you'll be able to see more clearly that
"/presentation" is the name given to the repo on github, and within that repo, the branch taken as a reference for GitHub Pages is called `react`, which within itself has the `index.html` file to be loaded (which is the one at location "/").

Comment: you are not understanding the problem react-router will get path route from location.href you understand but when you go to `https://<website>/presentation` the route path is `/presentation` however your app set here (`index.html`) only serves the route path as `/` and the fact you want it to run that way means that the implementation needs to set `/presentation` as `path root`. try it here is the solution for you

Comment: Hello, I've been trying several approaches and you're actually right. I
I initially thought that it was enough to indicate "base:/presentation/" and the SPA should work normally, but I really had to make the change you suggested. Thank you very much.
By the way, however, I managed to solve other problems such as the 404 error when refreshing, but this problem is completely resolved on the computer, but on the mobile phone if I leave the SPA and go back to the SPA again, the 404 error is displayed. Do you know anything about this?

Comment: that's because the paths don't really exist you can create a `404.html` file in `public` and use any method to redirect back to `index.html` for example `<meta http- equiv='refresh' content='0;url=<url>'>` or use javascript

Comment: I used Javascript, as I resorted to a repository for SPA on github, called "spa-github-pages" from a user called "rafgraph", which uses this approach. But I'm going to take a closer look at this repository and your suggestion, because I don't think I'm missing much, as this error only happens on my cell phone.
But anyway, if I can't solve the problem within a few days I'll make a new post here on stackoverflow. Thanks.