# React app deployment on GitHub Pages displays a blank page

Tags: reactjs, github, github-pages

I've developed a react app that is running fine locally. I'm now trying to deploy it using GitHub Pages.

Despite following this [tutorial](https://blog.logrocket.com/deploying-react-apps-github-pages/), I get a blank page, and several 404 errors in the logs.

Here is my `index.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import {HashRouter} from "react-router-dom";
import './index.css';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <HashRouter>
            <App />
        </HashRouter>
    </React.StrictMode>
);
```

And the Route defined in `App.js`

```
return (
    <>
        <Navbar/>
        <Routes>
            <Route path='/' element={<CoinsTable coins={coins}/>}/>
            <Route path='/coin' element={<CoinDetails/>}>
                <Route path=':coinId' element={<CoinDetails/>}/>
            </Route>
            <Route path='/option-prices' element={<CoinOptionsTable/>}>
                <Route path=':coinId' element={<CoinOptionsTable spotValue={1500} />}/>
            </Route>
        </Routes>

    </>
);
```

Here is the `homepage` property I've added to the project's `package.json`:

```
"private": false,
"homepage": "https://myusername.github.io/myusername/myreponame",
```

I've added this to `scripts`:

```
"predeploy": "npm run build",
"deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
```

Then I run this command to deploy the app:

```
npm run deploy
```

Comment: Does this help answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/71985764/8690857 If not, can you [edit] the post to include the router and routes you are rendering as part of a more complete [mcve]?

Comment: I found the error, thanks ! The problem was that I had repeated my github username in the homepage url before the app name. Correct value for "homepage" is: https://myusername.github.io/myappname

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the repeated github username from the homepage url fixed the problem:

Correct value for "homepage":

```
"homepage": "https://myusername.github.io/myreponame"
```