# Not able to handle routing of React app in github project pages because of homepage filed binding issue

Tags: reactjs, react-router, github-pages

I uploaded react app to github project pages. Github exposes the url as "user.github.io/reponame".
So I added "homepage" field in package.json and set the url value.

Now, it loads fine.. but due to the routing it messes up.

I have multiple routes in App.js like this.

```
<div className="App">
    <NavBar />
    <Routes>
        <Route path={"/photography/*"} element={<PhotographyRoute />} />
        <Route path={"/art/*"} element={<ArtRoute />} />
        <Route path={"/admin/*"} element={<AdminRoute />} />
        <Route path={"/"} element={<Home />} />
        <Route path={"*"} element={<NotFound />} />
    </Routes>
    <Footer />
</div>
```

and Links like this:

```
<header>
    <div className="nav-wrapper">
        <div className="brandwrapper">
            <Link to={"/"} id="brandname">
                <img
                    className="brand-logo"
                    src={"/assets/atom-icon.svg"}
                    alt="brand logo"
                />
            </Link>
        </div>

        <nav>
            <Routes>
                <Route
                    path={"/photography/*"}
                    element={
                        <Link to={"/photography/"}>
                            <strong id="photography">Photography</strong>
                        </Link>
                    }
                />
                <Route
                    path={"/art/*"}
                    element={
                        <Link to={"/art"}>
                            <strong id="art">Art</strong>
                        </Link>
                    }
                />
                <Route
                    path={"/"}
                    element={
                        <a href="#AboutMe">
                            Contact Me
                            <MaterialSymbolsContactsRounded id="contactIcon" />
                        </a>
                    }
                />
                <Route
                    path={"/admin/*"}
                    element={
                        <Link to={""}>
                            <strong id="art">
                                {sessionStorage.getItem(USER_TOKEN) ? "Admin" : ""}
                            </strong>
                        </Link>
                    }
                />
                <Route
                    path={"*"}
                    element={
                        <Link to={"/"}>
                            <strong>Home</strong>
                        </Link>
                    }
                />
            </Routes>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
```

When i load site with : "user.github.io/reponame", the route does not match with any of the route in app.js. It gives 404 page.. But technically react-router or react should handle this while bundling, using the homepage property.. But it does not. It only works for static files..

And when i click on any of the links the base url changes to "user.github.io/"..
When i click on Hone i.e "/" it should redirect to "user.github.io/reponame/" instead it redirects to "user.github.io/"..
Same way when i click on /photography it should redirect to "user.github.io/reponame/photography" instead it redirects to "user.github.io/photograophy" which again gives 404 page...

How can i make react router replace all urls with respect to base url (for routing) ? I don't want to hard-code routes..

PS. I also have nested routes.

I tried using %PUBLIC_URL%. But did not work.

Comment: Does this help answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/71985764/8690857 If not, then please [edit] the post to include a more complete [mcve] that includes all the router and routing setup/configuration.

Comment: It solved in a way.. but presented with 2 more issues.. 1.It disrupted <a href="#div" >, had to use react-router-hash-link package. 2. For getting static images, it works with  "user.github.io/reponame/" this url because react adds homepage url , but for "user.github.io/reponame" url  react considers home page as "user.github.io/", so images could not be loaded. 404 error. And moreover the hashrouter does not add / or /#/ at the end of the homepage url at startup.. that's why it is not able to set the base url properly.

Comment: Using process.env.PUBLIC_URL in src attribute of <img> tag kind of solves the problem of getting images from public/assets folder.. but react should always reffer to the homepage property, otherwise whats the point of setting "homepage" property. Any specific reason, why it is like that?