# I try to deploy my react app but it showing this error in github - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I try to host my react app in github but it is showing a blank page after hosting.
This is my repo:https://github.com/Hariprakash-va/Todolist/tree/gh-pages.

I try to deploy my react app but it is showing blank page.
I don't know what I'm missing or why it is showing as blank.

This is my hosting link: https://hariprakash-va.github.io/Todolist/

Comment: We can't see what any of your *actual* code is doing, but does this help answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/71985764/8690857

Answer (score 0):

Your URL is: https://hariprakash-va.github.io/Todolist/ but on your `package.json` you set the homepage to: https://hariprakash-va/github.io/Todolist and they are different.

I made a pull request to your repo, check that.