# How to use React router on github pages?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, github-pages

I was setting up a react router for the first time and then i pushed it to gh-pages. It worked when i only routed the contact page. When i added more pages it did not work anymore. It does work in my localhost. My index.js looks like this:

```
import React from "react"
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client"
import {App} from "./App"
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom"

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"))
root.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <App/>
        </BrowserRouter>
    </React.StrictMode>
)
```

My App.js looks like this:

```
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom"

import Home from "./pages/home";
import Contact from "./pages/contact";
import Nieuws from "./pages/nieuws";
import Openingstijden from "./pages/openingstijden";
import Producten from "./pages/producten";
import Prijzen from "./pages/prijzen";

export function App() {
    return (
        <Routes>
            <Route path="/KapsalonDeTussenstop/" element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="/KapsalonDeTussenstop/contact" element={<Contact />} />
            <Route path="/KapsalonDeTussenstop/nieuws" element={<Nieuws />} />
            <Route path="/KapsalonDeTussenstop/openingstijden" element={<Openingstijden />} />
            <Route path="/KapsalonDeTussenstop/prijzen" element={<Prijzen />} />
            <Route path="/KapsalonDeTussenstop/producten" element={<Producten />} />
        </Routes>
    )
}
```

My Home page does work (see image) so i think my gh-pages is good.
What do i need to do to fix this?

I tried to follow instructions and I tried to do the routing it worked, but after that not anymore. I also tried hashrouter but then it is also not working on localhost.

Comment: Are you getting an error message in the console? What does it say?

Comment: @kzi My console only says: GET https://dave-nbg.github.io/favicon.ico [HTTP/2 404 Not Found 0ms]

​But that doesn't look like a problem to me

Comment: O sorry i found another error: 

-Content-Security-Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“default-src”).

- Content-Security-Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at https://dave-nbg.github.io/favicon.ico (“img-src”).

- Content-Security-Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“default-src”).

Comment: I just tried https://dave-nbg.github.io/
Looks like there's nothing served at all, I'm getting an error 404.

Comment: @kzi It is this link: https://dave-nbg.github.io/KapsalonDeTussenstop/

Comment: The Contact link on your homepage has `/KapsalonDeTussenStop/contact` as target, but it has to be `/KapsalonDeTussenstop/contact`, I think (small s in Tussenstop). Then you have to make sure, that your index.html is served always, regardless of the path. I configured this with an apache2 webserver already but not with github pages. But maybe this will help you: https://itnext.io/so-you-want-to-host-your-single-age-react-app-on-github-pages-a826ab01e48

Comment: Does this help answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71984401/react-router-not-working-with-github-pages/71985764#71985764

Answer (score 0):

First of all, use `exact` in  `<Route />`

```
        <Routes>
            <Route exact path="/KapsalonDeTussenstop/" element={<Home />} />
            <Route exact path="/KapsalonDeTussenstop/contact" element={<Contact />} />
            <Route exact path="/KapsalonDeTussenstop/nieuws" element={<Nieuws />} />
            <Route exact path="/KapsalonDeTussenstop/openingstijden" element={<Openingstijden />} />
            <Route exact path="/KapsalonDeTussenstop/prijzen" element={<Prijzen />} />
            <Route exact path="/KapsalonDeTussenstop/producten" element={<Producten />} />
        </Routes>
```

Also add a Homepage Route : ***`/`*** by writing.

`<Route exact path="/" element={ <Home /> } />`

Comment: I added this but it still doesn't work. I still get the same errors

Comment: Share the exact code snippet that you've tried lately. @DaveNieberg

Comment: ```export function App() {
    return (
        <Routes>
            <Route exact path="/" element={ <Home /> } />
            <Route exact path="/KapsalonDeTussenstop/" element={<Home />} />
            <Route exact path="/KapsalonDeTussenstop/contact" element={<Contact />} />
            <Route exact path="/KapsalonDeTussenstop/nieuws" element={<Nieuws />} />
            <Route exact path="/KapsalonDeTussenstop/openingstijden" element={<Openingstijden />} />
 
        </Routes>
    )
}```

Comment: i deleted the imports because it was to long

Answer (score 0):

I kind of solved the problem. It did not work if i types in the path like /contact. The button with the exact path was also not working. This button did work: `<Link to="/contact">Go to About Page</Link>`