# How to implement multiple subroutes with a reactJS app hosted on GitHub Pages?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, github-pages, prerender

I use reactJS for a multiple routes app.

Historically, I hosted my app on [Netlify](https://www.netlify.com/), then I implement a prerendering with `react-spa-prerender` in order to improve SEO.

Recently I migrate it towards GitHub pages, keeping this prerendering effective.

Then, I try to get rid of this prerendering and my subpages were not served anymore.

My `App.js` returns this :

```
return (
        <>
            <div className="App" id="capture">
                <AppContext.Provider value={appContext} > 
                    <div className={`${theme}`}>
                        <BrowserRouter>
                             <Routes>
                                <Route exact path={pathBuilder('/')} element={<CurriculumVitae domain={EnumDomain.GENERIC}  />} />
                                <Route path={pathBuilder('/dev')} element={<CurriculumVitae domain={EnumDomain.DEV} />} />
                                <Route path={pathBuilder('/maths')} element={<CurriculumVitae domain={EnumDomain.MATHS} />} />
                            </Routes> 
                        </BrowserRouter>
                    </div> 
                </AppContext.Provider>
            </div>
        </>
);
```

The method `pathBuilder(path)` return this :

```
const pathBuilder = (path) => {
    return `${process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? '/cv' : ""}${path}`;
}
```

This is due to the fact that the app is served on GitHub Pages at `"https://[githubname].github.io/cv"`, and the base domain page is `"https://[githubname].github.io"`, I have to add the suffix `'/cv'` and then add the good suffix corresponding to the page (`'/'`, `'/dev'`, `'/maths'`).

Here are my dependencies in `package.json` :

```
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.16.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "react-spa-prerender": "^1.0.14",
```

Can somebody help me with this problem ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't see overt issues with the code you have shared, specifically, so perhaps the issue is elsewhere. Does this help answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71984401/react-router-not-working-with-github-pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [the post suggested by @Drew Reese](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71984401/react-router-not-working-with-github-pages), effectively it was due of the fact that I migrate towards GitHub Pages, which not supports [BrowserRouter](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/router-components/browser-router) anymore.

I share the code that works for me.

I replace this :

```
<BrowserRouter>
     <Routes>
         <Route exact path={'/'} element={<CurriculumVitae domain={EnumDomain.GENERIC}/>} />
         <Route path={'/dev'} element={<CurriculumVitae domain={EnumDomain.DEV} />} />
         <Route path={'/maths'} element={<CurriculumVitae domain={EnumDomain.MATHS} />} />
     </Routes> 
</BrowserRouter>
```

by that :

```
<RouterProvider router={router} />
```

You only have to create the router before, with the method `createHashRouter()` :

```
import { createHashRouter, RouterProvider } from 'react-router-dom';


const router = createHashRouter(
     [
        {
            path: "/",
            errorElement: <Error />,
            children : [
                {
                    path: "/",
                    element: <CurriculumVitae domain={EnumDomain.GENERIC} />
                 },
                 {
                     path: "dev",
                     element: <CurriculumVitae domain={EnumDomain.DEV} />
                 },
                 {
                     path: "maths",
                     element: <CurriculumVitae domain={EnumDomain.MATHS} />
                 }
            ]
        }
    ]
);
```

Now I have three routes :

1. the home hosted at `"https://<github-name>.github.io/<git-repo>"`
2. two subroutes hosted at `"https://<github-name>.github.io/<git-repo>/#/<subroute>"`